# Tomcat maxthreads, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: java, tomcat

In the catalina.out I saw this message appearing in the log:

`Maximum number of threads (200) created for connector with address null and port 80`

Does this mean a process is hogging something or do I need to just increase the thread size?

After restarting tomcat, I had spam like this message:
`"SEVERE: The web application [/MyServlet] is still processing a request that has yet to finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You can control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation."`

Is there a way to solve my situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it sounds like you've got some request handler which never completes. Each time it's invoked, it'll basically soak up another thread, until you've run out of threads in the pool.

You need to work out *which* request is failing to complete, and fix the code. If you can take a dump of the stacks of all threads, it's likely to become clear which requests are failing to complete.

Comment: Whenever a call is made to the servlet a response is received, so it does not mean it fails to complete? Could it be that due to large traffic, it's taking up 1 thread per request, and it's slow to complete before another batch of requests come in?

Comment: @Maurice: Well, it sounds like not *all* requests are really receiving a response. Both of your messages point to the same cause - it seems reasonable to assume for the moment that this really *is* the cause. Don't forget that there may be requests you never see explicitly, e.g.  for favicon.

Comment: @JonSkeet do you have a link or any more concrete suggestions what to look for in the thread dump? What do you have to look for code-wise in order to be sure the thread is returned properly (RUNNABLE --> WAITING).

Comment: @basZero: If the thread dump shows where each thread is (what method it's executing) that should give you enough information, I suspect.